# how to use linux rename

Tags: linux, rename

i'm embarrassed i even have to ask but I have a directory with m4a files that have the number of the track from the cd appended to the beginning of the filename, such as this:

```
1-01 Smash.m4a
```

how can I remove the "1-01 " using rename? or any other linux command for that matter. If it makes a difference, i'm on fedora-13.

EDIT (bonus points if you can explain why this doesn't work) just as a test, i tried this:

```
rename 1-0?? SSS *.m4a
```

without any changes made to any of the filenames in the directory

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Give this a whirl (in the directory with the files you want to rename):-

```
for i in *; do mv -v "$i" "$(echo "$i" | cut -f2- -d ' ')"; done
```

Comment: well, i don't know what this is (perl?) but it worked on all but one filename. to be fair, it is the special case in the directory: 1-04 Bass Suite #1.m4a     ...the problem is, i'm still no more knowledgeable about rename. Is this not doable with rename?

Comment: It's just shell... so you should be able to run that straight from the commandline. I'd imagine it is doable with rename, but I've not used it much myself.

Comment: `rename 's/^\d+-\d+\s//g' *.m4a` should do the trick, though!

Comment: In UNIX-like systems, the shell is quite a bit more powerful than in non-UNIX-like systems (such as the Windows family of operating systems).  Fortunately, Microsoft is trying hard to change that, and make it's CLI more powerful and useful (though I don't really agree with how they go about it).  On UNIX-like systems, including Linux, the command line is built around tiny, single-purpose programs that lend themselves to being easily chained together.  "Do one thing, and do it well," is pretty much the underlying philosophy.

Comment: that rename command doesn't seem to work either...

Comment: Odd... I created a few files with the same naming convention you're using, and it works fine. How are you running it?

Comment: just copied and pasted. I was in the directory with all the .m4a's.

Comment: That's a bit weird. Any errors of any kind?

Comment: rename 's/^\d+-\d+\s//g' *.m4a

Comment: .no errors, no.

Comment: @Ramy, @Andy: On Debian, `rename` is actually `prename`, a Perl script that uses regexes. On other systems, `rename` is a much simpler utility (from `util-linux-ng`, IIRC) which only accepts fixed "from" and "to" strings.

Comment: @Michael: Process creation costs a lot more on WinNT than it does on most Unix-like OSes. (This is why threads are more common on Windows than `fork()` is.)

Comment: @grawity Cheers for that... I was going on it being the `perl`-based one, and to keep things to a minimum I went for the shell-only option ;-) Thanks for the tip though!

Comment: @grawity, i'm on fedora-13. I don't believe that's a debian system. Also, there is a man-page for "rename" which looks like this: http://linux.die.net/man/1/rename

Comment: @grawity Yes, I am aware; according to a paper from Microsoft, process creation is approx. 2% as expensive on an average UNIX like system compared to Windows (at least as of WinXP)... pretty heavy penalty for process creation.  That is, I believe, a bug in the Windows system.  Of course, I'm just a puny free software user, so what do I know?  :^)

Comment: @Ramy: Linking to manpages at http://linux.die.net/ is pointless, since I just said that different distros package different programs with the same name.

Comment: @grawity: right, but...don't the man-pages on my machine mean anything? There wouldn't be a man page entry on my machine for something not installed right? The link i sent you is what the manpage entry on my machine looks like.